# lucid 10.04 LTS => Precise 12.04.1 : upgrade doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, server, upgrade

I googled and looked into all known issues on ubuntu forums related to distribution upgrade but I can't figure out why a 10.04 LTS server won't detect the last LTS 12.04.1. I guess since 12.04 is a fresh dist, not much is reported for related issues

Here is what I did :

```
apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

apt-get install update-manager-core
```

it was already installed so no update for this package.

I checked : /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

```
[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

I also checked my sourcelist before running apt-get : /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
# deb http://landscape.canonical.com/packages/hardy ./
# deb-src http://landscape.canonical.com/packages/hardy ./
```

and then following Ubuntu guide for Precise upgrade the command below should work :

```
root@xxxxxxxxx:/etc/apt# do-release-upgrade  -d
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I tried without dev release option -d but got the same result

Kernel :

```
root@xxxxxxxxx:/etc/apt# uname -a
Linux XXXXXXXXX 2.6.32-42-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 25 15:57:54 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Linux Distrib :

```
root@XXXXXXXXX:/etc# cat lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"
```

Source list :

```
root@XXXXXXXXX:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

So am I missing something ?

The server was accessing outside through a proxy but I grant direct access to this server to avoid any Internet access problem or redirection but no clue...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Nobody to help :( ? I'm running out of options.. I guess I'm going with a CD/DVD upgrade but I want to know why it doesn't work before..

Comment: May be I'm missing a package source url ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running 'do-release-upgrade' without the '-d' option? From what I remember the '-d' option is only used to upgrade to an alpha/beta version of the OS.

```
do-release-upgrade --help

Usage: do-release-upgrade [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -V, --version         Show version and exit
  -d, --devel-release   Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is
                        possible
```

Comment: yes I tried that too and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

[Found this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_to_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS).

The page linked to from above says:

1. Start System/Administration/Software Sources
2. On the Updates tab, set Show new distribution releases: to Long term support releases only, then press Close.
3. Press Alt-F2 and type `update-manager -d`

   1. Click the Check button to check for new updates. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
   2. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release. Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.

I take this to mean you **must** do it graphically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my server is not running in a graphical environment...and I can't install a GUI on it

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth doing

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to ensure it upgrades everything to current 10.04.4 on the existing OS first; i.e. that which `apt-get upgrade` won't upgrade.

Comment: Tried that too : root@XXXXXXXX:/etc/apt# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
root@XXXXXXXXXX:/etc/apt# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  vnc4server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

copy paste in your source.list and run do-release-upgrade.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 10.04.2 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release amd64 (20110211.1)]/ lucid main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 10.04.2 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release amd64 (20110211.1)]/ lucid main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
```